# Which program is good for modifying pictures?

Tags: software, post-processing

I want to modify my photos so they look better but I don't know which is good and simple to use. I use a windows Vista.

Comment: what's your budget? I find Photoshop does pretty much everything I could want, from the RAW conversion to image manipulation (removing unwanted elements) to strange effects.

Comment: i'd loved it to be free :)

Comment: Alternatives to Photoshop:  http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4707/what-are-the-alternatives-to-photoshop-is-gimp-a-good-option

Comment: Free alternatives: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/free-program-for-editing-pictures

Answer (score 6):

If you want something simple and free, I think [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) is a good tool.
If you want more power for free, The [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) is a great tool. But it's harder to use.
If you want power and you're ready to pay, [Lightroom](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshoplightroom/) is the best for me!

Answer (score 3):

The [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org) software is free and powerful, but you will have to invest some time to learn how to work with it b/c it is a fully capable image editor (Photoshop style).

Comment: oh ok I'll test it

Answer (score 2):

Try Paint.net, it has some cool filters and it can work with layers, it's sort of an advanced Paint.

Answer (score 1):

You could clarify your question you could get more precise answers:

- Do you work with JPEG files or with Camera RAW files
- What's your budget
- Does your goal is to just make your family photos better?

Paint.net will cover most of your basic needs.