# Photo organiser (for mac), hopefully free

Tags: geotagging, tagging

Hi there i am quite new to photography and i would to know which is the best free photo organiser program (for Mac)?

For organiser i mean a program that would let me add tags to my photos, add descriptions, add a map tag, etc.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Doesn't the built in iPhoto program do this already?

Comment: My mac does not came with it :/

Comment: "Photos" is the free app that comes with recent releases of OS X. If you have equipment that can run 10.10 it may be worth it to upgrade if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to **[iPhoto](https://www.apple.com/mac/iphoto/)** (pre-OSX 10.10) or **[Photos](http://www.apple.com/osx/photos/)** (either of which should have come free with your machine, but apparently didn't), then a free package you may want to look into obtaining, assuming you don't want more sophisticated editing controls or a RAW converter, is Google's [**Picasa**](https://picasa.google.com/).

See [Free program for editing pictures](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/free-program-for-editing-pictures) for a list of other possible candidates if you are interested in photo processing.